# How to use variables in nuget.config repositoryPath and csproj Reference HintPath

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

My company has NuGet package reference trouble due to our use of [Multi-Homed Projects](https://blog.nuget.org/20141010/nuget-is-broken.html#multi-homed-projects):

> It's pretty common to include a project in mutliple solutions. Unfortunately, NuGet cannot understand when this is the case. And because NuGet uses a packages folder at the solution level, the Hint Paths in projects become relative to the solution. If there are multiple solutions using a project, these relative paths can easily break.

I'm trying to figure out a reasonable way to keep the Hint Paths from breaking.

One idea I had was to use an environment variable to point to a shared package folder (similar to how NuGet does it with .NET Core projects).

I've tried to create a `nuget.config` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\shared_packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

And when I install a package it generates a Hint Path with a relative path:

```
<Reference Include="QRCoder, Version=1.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Users\Username\.nuget\shared_packages\QRCoder.1.3.5\lib\net40\QRCoder.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This won't work on other machines so I have to manually edit the `.csproj` file to something like this:

```
<Reference Include="QRCoder, Version=1.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\shared_packages\QRCoder.1.3.5\lib\net40\QRCoder.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Can I configure `nuget.config` (or something else?) to make the Hint Path use the literal value of `$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\shared_packages` so I don't have to manually edit the `.csproj` file every time?

Comment: NuGet always uses relative paths for references if you are using a packages.config file. If you do not want hint paths you could instead look at using PackageReferences - these do not include hint paths in the project. The only thing you can do with projects using a packages.config file is have the NuGet.Config in some parent directory of all the solutions then define a path here which all solutions would use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to use variables in nuget.config repositoryPath and csproj Reference HintPath

Just like Matt said, "*NuGet always uses relative paths for references if you are using a packages.config file.*". And, AFAIK, there is no such configurein `nuget.config` (or something else?) to make the Hint Path use the literal value of `$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\shared_packages`.

To resolve this question, you can use Package references (`PackageReference`) instead of packages.config in project files. With `PackageReference`, your packages are point to the shared package folder (similar to how NuGet does it with `.NET Core` projects), even if you are using the .NET framework.

To use the `PackageReference`, go to the Tools->NuGet PackageManager->Package Manage Settings:

[image]

Then you can add your packages to your project, all the packages are stored in the `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`.

Besides, you can [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) for those projects which install the packages with `packages.config`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when the majority of client applications which consume the multi-homed projects are ASP.NET projects. You do not support PackageReference here for some reason. Was it really too much to ask that the packages.config implementation utilize the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable for example?

Comment: Or even better, just use the default globalPackagesFolder that PackageReference uses so it just works and nothing has to be done on a clean developer system?