# VSTS - How to update Nuget Packages without losing $(solutiondir) in csproj

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

**Problem:**
We have an issue with our VSTS build pipelines, in that we are using the $(SolutionDir) in our csproj. The issue that we are running into is, we cannot update our Nuget Packages because whenever we do, we lose the $(SolutionDir) and have to go into the csproj and put $(SolutionDir) back into the correct places.

**Question:**
Is there a way to set the build (or anything else), so that we do not need to manually modify the csproj? We would like to add/update a nuget package, and know that it will be handled properly in the build every time when we check it in? Maybe even add $(SolutionDir) automatically.

Comment: Why not update your csproj from your solution in your dev environment with anything you want, push that to the repo and DevOps will read from that. Edit: Sorry just reread that. Why do you have a variable in csproj and what does it do?

Comment: Why does updating the Nuget packages overwrite the $(SolutionDir) property? You can add variables to your build pipeline in VSTS (edit your build and click on the Variables tab).

Comment: Jabberwocky, it is a Microsoft Macro. I think there are build/restore issues on other machines who have a different directory setup than you do. So SolutionDir, when deploying, forces it to look at the correct location. It's a known macro online.

Comment: DomBurf I'm not sure. Whenever I update a nuget package, I look at the csproj and it replaces $(SolutionDir)/packages/newton/etc with ../packages/newton/etc


Problem seems to be that if I add variables do the csproj, then they get overwritten when I update the nuget package.

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)` was the garbage used by obsolete NuGet package restore, which you should not use any more. You should migrate away from that.

Comment: You might want to aim at using the PackageReference syntax and use the version ranges in your .csproj. Then a nuget restore will pull (read: update) according to the range.

Comment: Am I understanding? 
- You use the macro and have it committed to source control
- Your VSTS build has a NuGet step to "update" the packages
- When that step runs, your .csproj is rewritten without the macro
- The build fails because your pkg isn't in the right place anymore

Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VSTS - How to update Nuget Packages without losing $(solutiondir) in csproj

I am afraid you could not do such things. We could edit the `.csproj` manually to se the `$(SolutionDir)` in our `.csproj` file, but NuGet doesn't support this, NuGet always uses relative paths for references if you are using a `packages.config` file.

That the reason why nuget overwrite the `$(solutiondir)` when you add/update a nuget package. And there is no such setting that we could use the `$(solutiondir)` automatically.

To resolve this issue, you can try to use `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config`. `PackageReference` does not make any changes to the project files and packages are discovered from a user wide location.

Check the document [NuGet is now fully integrated into MSBuild](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html) and [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154786/how-to-use-variables-in-nuget-config-repositorypath-and-csproj-reference-hintpat) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, so is package reference the new way of handling nuget packages so that you don't need to modify the csproj and add $(SolutionDir) or anything else?

Comment: @Godrules500, Yes.

Comment: I will see if I can convince my old school friends here lol. Is there any other way that you know of to handle this without switching to PackageReference?